# Display Gutenberg content in page template PHP file

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Firts time I trying to create page using WordPress with new editor called Gutenberg. In Wordpress I Always using:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

to display content but it is not working with Gutenberg. Is there some new way to display content when I using Gutenberg in PHP page templates files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `the_content();` inside the WordPress `while` loop like below.

```
if ( have_posts() ) { 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
}
```